# Draw text on different co-ordinates in open gl GL10

Tags: android, opengl-es

I wonder if there is an easy way to draw some texts on different different co-ordinates. eg; I have a text like

```
t1 "this is text1", 
t2 "this is text2", 
t3 "this is text3"
```

Now I want to render these texts on different co-ordinates like

```
t1 at(x1,y1);
t2 at(x2,y2);
t3 at(x3,y3);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know what u need but may be [this](http://blog.fujiu.jp/2011/05/android-opengl-es.html) will help you.

Comment: Embed the relevant info (and in English).  Links alone are insufficient.